# Estimating the noise covariance matrix in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear, covariance-matrix

Given

y = x*B + e,

where x is a p dimensional vector of inputs, and y is a one dimensional response variable. If the noise term is not necessarily i.i.d., but zero-mean Gaussian, how would I estimate the covariance matrix of the noise/error given only N samples of x and y.

Comment: Maybe worth reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares...

Comment: @seanv507 That method is for a *known* covariance matrix: it does not concern estimating that matrix. It is difficult simultaneously to estimate the matrix and fit the model. Various sophisticated methods exist to do this depending on the application, including Gaussian process regression, time series analysis, Kriging, mixed modeling, and much more. This variety alone indicates why it is important to be more specific about the covariance: the more you can pin it down, the better are your prospects of being able to estimate (and of being able to do so with well-tested techniques and software).

Comment: so at least in the wiki article, it mentions *feasible* GLS when the covariance is not known. (and agree on pinpointing the details of the covariance)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas :), I'll dig a bit more.